# Reverse Proxy Performance vs No Proxy?

Tags: node.js, performance, proxy, reverse-proxy, server

Using node.js, how much performance am I likely to use (in an approximate percentage) if I use a reverse proxy from nginx to the node.js servers instead of not having a proxy and just having the node.js servers at the front lines?

Comment: I get better performance *with the proxy*.

Comment: why would that be? I'm pretty new to this stuff

Comment: It's one of those things I don't really question, but nginx is just magic for most applications.

Answer (score 0):

There is no single answer to this question. There are a lot of variables that affect performance,  especially the configuration of the proxy (nginx or haproxy for example) and what the node application is doing. For example, having the proxy handle TLS and having node talk plain HTTP to the proxy vs having node handle the TLS itself will quite often make a big difference (currently).

Because there are so many variables, you should really perform your own benchmarks for your node app to see what is the right fit for your use case.